# How to change the numbering of image captions?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2007

I have written a pretty long document in MS word and I have multiple image captions generated by the app. I have multiple level headers, and the numbering of captions is currently something like `level 1 . level 2 . number of image in chapter` i.e. "1.2.3" is the third image in chapter 1.2.

I'd like to change the numbering to be absolute - so that the first image gets number 1, and the 12th image get number 12th (dismiss the information about chapters). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you may only need to go to **References, Captions, Insert Caption, Numbering** and uncheck **Include chapter number**.